# How to put multiple UITextFields into one string on Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4

I have 6 UITextfields and I would like to put them all into one string so I can get what was inputted into the UItextField.

Example: In UItextfield1, I entered the number "3", then in UItextfield2, I entered the number "5", and so on. I would like to put this into one string so it reads "35" ....

Below is my code. Any help would be great!

```
class EnterUsersCode: UIViewController {

    var textField1: UITextField! = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.text = ""
        return tf
    }()

    var textField2: UITextField! = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.text = ""
        return tf
    }()

    var textField3: UITextField! = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.text = ""
        return tf
    }()

    var textField4: UITextField! = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.text = ""
        return tf
    }()

    var textField5: UITextField! = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.text = ""
        return tf
    }()

    var textField6: UITextField! = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.text = ""
        return tf
    }()

    var textFieldArray: [UITextField] {
        return [textField1!, textField2!, textField3!, textField4!, textField5!, textField6!]

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try

```
 let str = "\(textField1.text)\(textField2.text)"
```

or to get all strings concatenated in one string

```
let str = textFieldArray.compactMap{$0.text}.joined()
```

Comment: Nice use of `flatMap` (er, `compactMap`. That change is going to take me a while to get used to...)

Answer (score 2):

Use your `textFieldArray` to get the textfields and append the string from `text` property to a variable by looping through it:

```
func getConsolidatedString() -> String {
    var finalString = ""
    for textField in textFieldArray {
        finalString += textField.text ?? ""
    }
    return finalString
}
```

Comment: no need for ?? "" ,,, as it's the default value even if the text has not set

Comment: Yes, that’s not needed according to the case of the question, but what if the text is set to `nil` explicitly??? Default value is for the safety.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate your string by using + like below:

```
let str = textField1.text + textField2.text + textField3.text + textField4.text + textField5.text + textField6.text
```